# If in a string method parameters is negative, are we still count from zero from back?

Tags: javascript, string, slice

What is should count to e (in the last) 0 or 1?

```js
var word = "My_name_is_Joe";
console.log(word.slice(-3,-1));
```

Comment: You could have test it to get your answer.

Answer (score 1):

`word.slice(-3,-1)` will take the last three charecter (e.g. `Joe`) and remove the last character (e.g `e`) from the selected three character.

The output would be `Jo`

Answer (score 1):

Your question is "why is 'e' not included"? [Here's why](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) (emphasis mine)

> **endIndex**
>
> Optional. The zero-based index **before which** to end extraction. **The character at this index will not be included.** If `endIndex` is omitted, `slice()` extracts to the end of the string. If negative, it is treated as `strLength + endIndex` where `strLength` is the length of the string (for example, if `endIndex` is -3 it is treated as `strLength - 3`).

Answer (score 1):

Following the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice you will find information that the second argument is optional.

> str.slice(beginIndex[, endIndex])

Going farther, you can call slice method with begin argument as negative value, as you did. Then begin would be treated as offset from the end of the string.

To reach 'e' in your string you can do one of two things that come to my mind:

1. Call slice without end argument `word.slice(-3);`.
2. Or call `word.slice(-3,word.length);`

Both of then returns last three characters (`-3`).